# How to identify software used to create an old 90's .PCB file?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I have a .pcb file from the 90's. It was created as a student project, and because it was 30 years ago, I simply can't remember what software was used to create it.

Any ideas on how I might be able to identify the software? Or, is there software I might be able to use that can open a vast number of different kinds of formats? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try opening it in notepad++ or another text editor and see if there's any human-readable text.

Comment: @MattS No human-readable text at all, other than labels I had put in. Does the fact that it doesn't identify the software give any hints on what software it might be?

Comment: There were at least a dozen major PCB software packages kicking around in the 90's. Maybe see if something on [this page](https://madpcb.com/history-of-pcb-design/) rings a bell?

Comment: question about which program can open multiple files is a better fit at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=file+signature+list&ia=web

Comment: if you have a Linux (or \*BSD, which *I think* include Mac OS) machine, you most likely have `file` installed (on windows, install it [this way](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)), running it on your file (so, `file yourfile.pcb`) will take an educated guess on what it is. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @MarcusMüller That was the first thing I tried. It returns "data".

Comment: @Ana that's a rather bad sign… Any modern PCB layout tool (and that's what .pcb would suggest) does have rather well-detected formats. `strings yourfile.pcb` doesn't yield anything useful, either, I guess?